# Intransitive "überlegen" or Transitive "überlegen"

Tags: verb

> Schon mal überlegt, Lehrerin zu werden?

I wonder exactly what phrase is omitted from the beginning of this sentence.

> (**Hast du**) schon mal überlegt, Lehrerin zu werden? {Intransitive "überlegen"}
>
> (**Hast du dir**) schon mal überlegt, Lehrerin zu werden? {Transitive "überlegen"}

Do you need to include "dir" here?

Comment: FWIW, *überlegen* is used transitively in both examples (the infinitive group *Lehrerin zu werden* being the direct object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, both versions would be correct and appropriate, so it's pure guessing to speculate what phrase is omitted.